# iterate through undefined/null objects in a react element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a super simple react element like this below:

```
const Stores = ({ stores }) => {
  const renderStores = () => Object.keys(stores).map(store => {    
    return (
      <div key={store}>
        { store }        
      </div>
    )
  })

  return (
    <div>
      { renderStores() }
    </div>
  )
}
```

It takes in `stores` (it's a POJO, not an array) as a prop and iterates through its keys to display the name of the store.

The problem is when I write react elements this way, the `stores` isn't defined or could be null at this point in my app and this causes `Object.keys` 
to throw an error because you can't iterate through undefined or null.

What I want is the behavior of this react component to **render nothing** if `stores` is undefined or null.

I would like to avoid the need to wrap my `renderStores` function and check for undefined/null:

```
const Stores = ({ stores }) => {
  const renderStores = () => {
    if (stores) {
      return Object.keys(stores).map(store => {    
        return (
          <div key={store}>
            { store }        
          </div>
        )
      })  
    } else {
      return <div></div>
    }    
  }

  return (
    <div>
      { renderStores() }
    </div>
  )
}
```

But this isn't easy on the eyes.

I could instead do this:

```
return (
  <div>
    { stores ? renderStores() : '' }
  </div>
)
```

But this seems like boilerplate.

Is there a better way or a common convention to protect `Object.keys()` from throwing an error when undefined/null is passed in to be iterated in a react element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `stores` is `null` or `undefined`, it's falsy, and you could use a logical OR to just use an empty object instead, which would have no keys, an no iteration would happen

```
Object.keys(stores||{}).map(...
```

you wouldn't get an empty element though, you'd need a condition for that

Comment: If you want to use this approach - just use a default - `const Stores = ({ stores = {} }) => {` It's much more obvious what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

I think the way you are managing it initially is the correct approach. I the concern is how that looks, you can clean things up a bit in this way:

```
const Stores = ({ stores }) => {
  const renderStores = () => {
    if !(stores) return null;
    return Object.keys(stores).map(store => (
      <div key={store}>
        { store }        
      </div>
    ))    
  }

  return (
    <div>
      { renderStores() }
    </div>
  )
}
```

This will return a `null` when there are no `stores` and render just the `<div></div>`.

You could also add a default in the arguments like this:

```
    const Stores = ({ stores = {} }) => {
```

This would allow you to essentially return nothing from the map of the keys.

The third option, would be to not render `stores` from the parent if `stores` is `null`.  This would be the cleanest option for you potentially.

```
// parent.js

{ data ? <Stores stores=data /> : null }

// stores.js
const Stores = ({ stores }) => (
  <div>
    { 
      Object.keys(stores).map(store => (
        <div key=store>
          {store}        
        </div>
      ))
    }
  </div>
)
```

If you have an empty state you need to maintain, you can pass that in falsey return of the conditional.

I do this quite often multiple ways.

Comment: I may not have exactly the correct syntax for the last example - let me know if it doesn't work and I can update.